# How to determine if the implicit curve is closed?

Tags: circles, plane-curves

Let the implicit equation 
$$F(x,y)=0, \quad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$
defines a curve $\gamma$.

The **question** is what properties must have the function $F$, s.t. the curve $\gamma$ be topologically equivalent to circle?

It seems if $\operatorname{Hess}F$ is positive defined on some simply-connected domain containing the curve, then the curve must be closed. Is it correct? Is  there a theorem about this topic?

Answer (score 3):

That's not quite correct.   For example, your curve could be empty, or a single point, or a line segment.  If the Hessian matrix is positive definite on some convex region $R$, then $F$ is a convex function there.  If $R$ is bounded, contains $\gamma$  and $\inf_R F < 0 \inf_{\partial R} F$, then $\gamma$ is the boundary of the convex open set $\{(x,y) \in R: F(x,y) < 0\}$, and this is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: thank u for the answer. As far as I understand this condition is sufficient, but not necessary.
For example, a border of a star is homeomorphic to a circle, but the star-domain is not convex in common case. The curve $\rho=2+cos(8\phi)$ is equivalent to circle, but hessian is not pos. def [see the plot](https://snag.gy/M30HGm.jpg). Is there a theorem with less-strong conditions?

Comment: This a very helpful answer for [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459726/convexity-of-the-graph-of-an-implicit-function). Could you please give me a reference to this result? Some kind of proof?